# HTML Form Box Field Won't Stay Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a project that requires a login form for the user to access the page. When the login button is clicked, I call the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#login").click(function(){
    $("#login").html('<form name="login" action="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><ul><li><label for="usermail">Email</label><input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required></li><li><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>  <li> <input type="submit" value="Login"></li>  </ul>  </form>  <form name="register" action="register" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  <ul>  <li><label for="username">Username</label>  <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required></li>  <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>  <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required></li>  <li><label for="password">Password</label>  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>  <li>   <input type="submit" value="Register"></li>  </ul>  </form> ');
});});
```

The div for the login button looks like this:

```
 <div class="row row1" id="login"><button>Login</br><p class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></p></button>
</row>
```

The current issue I'm having is that when you click into one of the boxes of the form, it won't let you stay clicked into that box. It immediately unclicks the box, making it impossible to login. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the click handler after you clicked the button?

Comment: ↑↑↑ I guess putvande get it right because of click event propagation

Comment: A.wolff suggestion was perfect.. but another way i posted too. You might like it also..

Answer (score 1):

With this code

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    $("#login").html('<form ... (very long string) ');
});});
```

You are effectively saying "when a user clicks on any part of the form, replace the contents of the form entirely". So the form gets overwritten with new contents every time you click on it. And the new contents are not "clicked" (you mean focused).

Comment: This is an explanation, not really an answer how to solve the problem

Comment: Maybe: `$("#login").one('click', function(){...});`

Comment: @putvande the question is literally "Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?". I explained why this is happening.

Comment: $("#login").one('click', function(){...}); did the trick! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another way i found out is to unbind click event: Use it for reference [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/1877/). It might give you better idea, so posting it too

```
$("#login").click(function(){ 
    $("#login").unbind('click');
    $("#login").html('<form..... >');
    .....
 });
```